# loop through MySQL result every 1 seconds using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a class which gets a result from the database and the result is being looped through, and the database is being updated regularly but i dont want to keep refreshing the page because of some reasons.

```
//file class.php

 class order {
     function getOrders(){
     //gets data from database

     }

 }

//file main.php

$ai = new order();

$orders = $ai->getOrders();

foreach($orders AS $order){

 //data displayed in a table
}
```

I want the table to be automatically updated without page reload.

I know i have to use ajax but i have no idea what to implement that in oop

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this.

```js
$(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $("#liveTable").load("path/to/orderList");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="liveTable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript and jQuery on your html page so as to reload a portion of the page.

you can add the following in your html page's head:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    theIntervalHandle = setInterval(fetchNewOrders,3000);
});

function fetchNewOrders()
{
    $('#ordersDiv').load('http://your.web.address/class.php');
}
</script>
```

and that

```
<div id="ordersDiv"></div>
```

inside your html file's body where you want the dynamic content to appear.
this assumes that the file that creates the output is called class.php and fetches data each 3 seconds as per second is quite often and can cause problems should your traffic increase beyond a few tens of users...